# What is the replacement of PDDocument.silentprint() in pdfbox version 2.0.0 and above?

Tags: pdfbox

I am switching to the pdfbox version 2.0.0 and wanted to know what is the replace for replacement of PDDocument.silentprint() in pdfbox version 2.0.0 and above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `PDDocument.silentprint()` mentioned by the OP effectively did something like

```
PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
job.setPageable(new PDPageable(this, job));
job.print();
```

According to the [PDFBox 2.0 Migration Guide](https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/migration.html#pdf-printing):

> #### PDF Printing
>
> With PDFBox 2.0.0 `PDFPrinter` has been removed.
>
> Users of `PDFPrinter.silentPrint()` should now use this code:
>
> ```
> PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
> job.setPageable(new PDFPageable(document));
> job.print();
> ```
>
> While users of `PDFPrinter.print()` should now use this code:
>
> ```
> PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
> job.setPageable(new PDFPageable(document));
> if (job.printDialog()) {
>     job.print();
> }
> ```
>
> Advanced use case examples can be found in th examples package under org/apache/pdfbox/examples/printing/Printing.java

Thus, for a `PDDocument document` the replacement for the 1.8.x

```
document.silentprint();
```

should be the 2.0.x

```
PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
job.setPageable(new PDFPageable(document));
job.print();
```